# Marshalling array of structs from .NET to C++: when does it do copying?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, pinvoke, marshalling

Consider a struct like System.Drawing.Point - one with LayoutKind.Sequential and containing only primitive members. I have a C# array of such structs.

I'm passing it to an (unmanaged) C++ function via P/Invoke. On the C++ side there's a corresponding definition of the struct (e.g. `struct Point { int x, y; };`). The function takes a `Point*` arg.

My question is, in what cases does the CLR copy the data and in what cases does it just pin it? Variables include:

- Array type: one-dimensional or rectangular
- C# definition of the function - using `Point*` or `Point[]` / `Point[,]`
- using `fixed(Point* pointer = array)` or not

I want to avoid the copying because it's slow.

Comment: It isn't documented, simple arrays just get pinned.  Use the debugger in case of doubt, type `*&array` to get the array address in C#.  And compare to the pointer value you get in the native code.  +8 in 32-bit mode.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much experience with pinning, but, according to my reading of MSDN, your structs should be pinned and not copied. Relevant refs:

1. [Marshalling data with PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhhdwae.aspx)
2. [Copying and pinning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23acw07k.aspx)
3. [Blittable and non-blittable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx)
4. [Default marshalling for value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t2cwe11.aspx)

From #2:

> Formatted blittable classes have fixed layout (formatted) and common data representation in both managed and unmanaged memory. When these types require marshaling, a pointer to the object in the heap is passed to the callee directly.

And your Point struct is given as an example in #3, so it qualifies as a blittable type.

I noticed some overhead to pinning objects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497018/what-is-the-overhead-of-c-sharp-fixed-statement-on-a-managed-unsafe-struct-conta/8499891#8499891), but that was for a `fixed byte[]`, which may be different to your `Point[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Structs are referenced by value and Classes are referenced by reference.

It means always you have a struct and you make an assignment its values are copied, like when you use int a = b; a  has the value of b and not point so b so if you change the value of a, b will not be updated.

If you have an array, internally it stores a vector of defaults, pointers for classes and the default value of structure for structs. Notice that if the struct contains a member which is a reference type (class) a pointer set to null is stored.

Supose you have

```
Point p = new Point(0, 1);
Point[] pa = new Point[10];
pa[0] = p;
++p.X;
```

Since Point is a struct (value type) when you print the values

```
p: {1, 1}
pa[0]: {0, 1}
pa[1-9]: {0, 0}
```

For C++ you can use foo(Point *pa) or foo(Point[] pa) for same results; in C# use foo(Point[] pa) in single dimension array. For a rectangular foo(Point **pa) in C++ and foo(Point[][]) in C#