# Is it possible to access unmanaged and managed array elements indiscriminately?

Tags: c#, unsafe, subscript

An example will make this clear:

```
unsafe void ProcessUnmanagedBuffer( float * buffer, int length )
{
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    {
        buffer[ i ] = ...;
    }
}

void ProcessManagedBuffer( float[] buffer, int length )
{
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    {
        buffer[ i ] = ...;
    }
}

// common interface to avoid duplicate code?
void ProcessBuffer( IndexableThing buffer, int length )
```

Of course, there can't be a common interface since float * isn't a class.

The obvious solution is to wrap and override the indexer, but for performance critical code this is far from ideal.

The less obvious one would be to pin the float[] and get a pointer to it. Better, but pinning incurs some overhead too.

I suspect there is no good solution - any ideas?

Comment: This may be helpful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32125/Unmanaged-Arrays-in-C-No-Problem  or here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of the first article, but not of that particular documentation page.

Comment: I can't really tell what this question is asking.  Use the *fixed* keyword in C# to generate a float* and bypass the array bounds check.  Make the ProcessManagedBuffer() method fast by not using the *length* argument but *buffer.Length* instead.  Which allows the jitter to see that the index can't ever be out of bounds, it eliminates the bounds check.  And whatever you do, profile first.  The bounds check is very cheap compared to the memory access.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, wasn't aware that using Array.Length resulted in optimizations - good to know!

Comment: @Hans Passant: I'm trying to avoid duplicate code in my audio processing classes: handling managed or unmanaged buffers ideally shouldn't result in 2 separate code paths. Fixed is a good idea, but I read it incurs quite a bit of overhead. I'll benchmark...

Comment: Found some benchmark result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497018/what-is-the-overhead-of-c-sharp-fixed-statement-on-a-managed-unsafe-struct-conta Doesn't look too good for fixed. I'll try pinning more persistently with GCHandle.Alloc.