# Get the sizeof a struct given the System.Type

Tags: c#, .net, sizeof

Given a struct `MyStruct`, I can get the size of instances of that struct using `sizeof(MyStruct)` in unsafe code. However, I want to get the size of a struct given the `Type` object for the struct, ie, `sizeof(typeof(MyStruct))`. There is `Marshal.SizeOf`, but that returns the *unmanaged* marshalled size, whereas I want the *managed* size of that struct.

Comment: Would a profiler meet your needs?

Comment: Not sure if anyone can answer this but why would the managed struct be a different size to the unmanaged one? Both are the same C# struct.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: I need to get the size of an arbitary struct at runtime

Comment: @thecoop - I figured but felt the need to ask regardless.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127707 In short: there is a *internal* overload of Marshal.SizeOf that returns the *managed* size of a struct.

Comment: @Lazarus: The marshaller applies several transformations to a struct before passing it to a native method via P/Invoke. The layout of structs in managed memory is different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no documented way to discover the layout of a managed struct.  The JIT compiler takes readily advantage of this, it will reorder fields of the struct to get the best packing.  Marshaling is *always* required to get a predictable layout, as directed by the `[StructLayout]` attribute.  You have to jump through the `Marshal.StructureToPtr()` hoop.  Whether you do it yourself or let the pinvoke marshaller do it for you.

`Marshal.SizeOf(Type)` gives you the size of the marshaled `struct`.  More background on why it works this way is available in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361986/how-to-check-the-number-of-bytes-consumed-by-my-structure/3362736#3362736).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the StructLayout attribute actually does affect how the CLR lays out the struct in managed memory. Only with LayoutKind.Auto the CLR is free to lay out the struct as it sees fit. Wih LayoutKind.Sequential (the default in C#) and LayoutKind.Explicit it's possible to get predictable layouts.

Comment: This is accurate.  A struct type has a default [StructLayout] if you don't apply one yourself.  Unlike a class.

Comment: Sou couldn't one use reflection to determine the layout for a struct with LayoutKind.Sequential or LayoutKind.Explicit and calculate its size this way?

Comment: @dtb - Type.StructLayoutAttribute.Kind is still Sequential, regardless of whether it was auto-generated or not.  Reflection doesn't provide the actual internal layout, only the marshaled layout.

Comment: Reflection doesn't provide any layout at all. It just tells you the fields of the struct and its attributes. The StructLayout attributes affects the layout of the struct in *managed* memory. With LayoutKind.Sequential (auto-generated or explicitly declared) and LayoutKind.Explicit (when explicitly declared) you can create a predictable struct layout in *managed* memory. Since the layout is determined by the StructLayout/FieldOffset attributes, which are discoverable using reflection, it should be possible to calculate the layout and thereby its size.

Comment: You do have to give the jitter a reason to swap fields.  Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918037/layout-of-net-value-type-in-memory

Comment: Is it documented how fields are swapped? If not, how are [memory mapped files supposed to work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd294099.aspx)?

Comment: No, the point I was trying to make.  Try to find insight in why it *did* take 4 versions of .NET to support the most common and powerful Windows NT feature.  Take a look with Reflector and find this statement that kicks off UnmanagedMemoryAccessor.Write<> after the exception checks:   uint num = Marshal.SizeOf<T>();

Comment: ECMA-335 doesn't seem to say if types marked `sequentiallayout` or `explicitlayout` (see e.g. Section 9.5.) can have their fields swapped or not, but from the wording I'd assume that only types marked `autolayout` are completely free in their layout. One section explicitly says: "[Rationale: This feature is used to lay out a managed value type in exactly the same way as an unmanaged C struct, allowing a managed value type to be handed to unmanaged code, which then accesses the fields exactly as if that block of memory had been laid out by unmanaged code. end rationale]"