# How can I find the size of a struct from a System.Type?

Tags: c#, .net, types, struct, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get the sizeof a struct given the System.Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472465/get-the-sizeof-a-struct-given-the-system-type)

Given a `System.Type` of a value type, how can I find its size?

```
// this works with a type identifier in an unsafe construct:
int size = sizeof(Guid);

// how in this (simplified) case?
Type t = Guid.Empty.GetType();
int size = t.GetSize();           // how?
```

I came up with recursively enumerating the members by reflection, but this doesn't give the correct size if packing is involved.

Now I'm going to try to create a generic method and use an instantiated type, but I think that won't work because instantiation by reflection creates an instance of type `object`. Expression trees? Hopefully I just hit my blind spot and there's something similar I miss at this late hour.

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361986/how-to-check-the-number-of-bytes-consumed-by-my-structure/3362736#3362736

Comment: @BrokenGlass Funny, I didn't find those questions when trying my initial search, no9r did they show up on the right pane. Still, I'm not sure if those answers work.